# Using Symbols in Wordpress Permalinks / URLs

Tags: asp.net, windows, wordpress, url, permalinks

The short problem: Editing the sanitize function has allowed me to add uppercase letters and symbols to my permalinks.  However, when I use a symbol (like: ".", "=", "?") the link ends up in a 404 error.  I'm guessing because the database can't access the page with a URL like that.

Are there any ways around this?

The long problem: I'm transitioning someone's site that was written in ASP on a windows server into a wordpress site.  I've copied each page's content and created a wordpress site that duplicates the site structure of the current ASP one.  But I need to keep the URL's the same, and his current site pages look like "http://thesite.com/ContentPage.aspx?page=subpage".

Comment: URL rewrite might be an option, https://blog.lextudio.com/2013/08/how-to-migrate-from-blogger-to-wordpress-on-windows-azure/

Comment: This seems like a sort of redirect.  I was hoping to avoid redirects.  Or is what you're saying is that it would load the wordpress version of the page "/2015/09/subpage" but that the final URL would end up looking like the old ASP URL "/ContentPage.aspx?page=subpage"?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page hierarchy, apply a rewrite rule and create a page template, to solve the problem without having to add extra content to the permalink and the final URL would end up looking like the old ASP URL.

The query variable 'page' holds the pagenumber for a single paginated Post or Page, using this queryvar isn't recommended. You should review the need to maintain the url structure.

Taking this page structure for example:

- Animals (permalink: http://thesite.com/animals/)

  - Lion (permalink: http://thesite.com/animals/lion)
  - Zebra (permalink: http://thesite.com/animals/zebra)
  - Others (permalink: http://thesite.com/animals/others)
- Flowers (permalink: http://thesite.com/flowers/)

If I access http://thesite.com/Animals.aspx?page=Lion I should be presented the "Lion" page

For this to work you have to add to your functions file the [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function with the following regex:

```
^([\w\d\-]*)(?:\.aspx?).*$
```

*(I'm not used to regexp so i guess there's an easier way to write it.)*

resulting in something like this:

```
  add_rewrite_rule('^([\w\d\-]*)(?:\.aspx?).*$','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]','top');
```

Use it in a function like [the example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Basic_Usage) in the Codex. This way you'll access http://thesite.com/index.php?pagename=Animals when entering http://thesite.com/Animals.aspx?page=Lion in the address bar.

*Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules.*

So now you must get the 'page' queryvar and do a custom query to get the page children. The best way to do this is creating a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use). Create a file aspx-template.php in your theme folder and add the following:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: aspx Template
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
  <?php
    $pagename = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_the_ID() );
    if ( isset($_GET['page']) ) :  $pagename .= '/' . sanitize_text_field( $_GET['page'] ); endif;

    $args = array(
      'post_type'   => 'page',
      'pagename'    => $pagename,
      'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    ?>
    <article>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </article><!-- #post-## -->
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <div>
      No page found
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Don't forget to associate the template to the parent page (Animals).

Comment: I added `function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^([\w\d\-]*)(?:\.aspx)?(?:\?page=)?([\w\d\-]*)(?:.*)$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]/$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');` and then when I try to open any page it tells me "Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in D:\Hosting\2947632\html\mywebsite\wp-includes\functions.php on line 13"

Comment: Where have you added the function? it must be on the _functions.php_ file inside the theme folder.

Comment: My mistake.  I had added the function to my _functions.php_ file inside my wp-includes folder.  So I removed that and added it instead to the _functions.php_ in my themes/mytheme folder.  No fatal errors.  I went to settings > permalinks and saved it to refresh my permalinks - but nothing.  No changes.  Same old URL structure.  I even set up an "animals" page as a parent and added a "lions" and "zebras" page as children.  It's still pulling them up with the url: Animals/Zebras/.

Comment: Can you check with the debug bar plugin the Query String and Matched Rewrite Rule? My guess is that the "page" var is already used by the wordpress to the pagination.

Comment: Okay, I got it working.  I was throwing in extra stuff that didn't need to be there.  Added `add_rewrite_rule('^([\w\d\-]*)(?:\.aspx)?(?:\?page=)?([\w\d\-]*)(?:.*)$','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]/$matches[2]','top');` directly to the theme's _functions.php_ and refreshed permalinks.  Now when I go to http://thesite.com/Animals.aspx?page=Lion its instead giving me http://thesite.com/Animals.aspx/?page=Lion.  And its loading the content from Animals, not from Lion.

Comment: _Request:_ Animals.aspx | _Query String:_ page=Lion&pagename=Animals%2F | _Matched Rewrite Rule:_ `^([\w\d\-]*)(?:\.aspx)?(?:\?page=)?([\w\d\-]*)(?:.*)$` | _Matched Rewrite Query:_ pagename=Animals/

Comment: The query variable 'page' holds the pagenumber for a single paginated Post or Page, using this queryvar isn't recommended. You should review the need to maintain the url structure. I've added a solution to retrieve the page with your url structure.

Comment: I tried to insert the custom query into my theme's page.php.  I also tried creating a custom template with the custom query.  It doesn't seem to have any effect.  I try navigating to thesite.com/Animals.aspx?page=Lion and its still loading thesite.com/Animals.aspx/?page=Lion with the Animals page.  I might be implementing the custom query code wrong.  I'm testing it on a fresh wordpress install using the twentyfifteen theme and my page.php code looks like http://thenewsite.denverglassreplacement.com/wordpress/page-dot-php/. I would like to make it up to you - jeremy@jrumatic.com

Comment: @Remie, I've update the answer, with a custom template solution.